# Composer conflict when installing craftcms/plugin-installer

Tags: craft3, composer

I have installed composer successfully but when I try to add:

```
composer require craftcms/plugin-installer
```

I get the following:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- craftcms/cms 3.0.0-RC4 requires craftcms/plugin-installer ~1.5.0 -> satisfiable by craftcms/plugin-installer[1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- craftcms/cms 3.0.0-RC4 requires craftcms/plugin-installer ~1.5.0 -> satisfiable by craftcms/plugin-installer[1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- craftcms/cms 3.0.0-RC4 requires craftcms/plugin-installer ~1.5.0 -> satisfiable by craftcms/plugin-installer[1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- Installation request for craftcms/cms 3.0.0-RC4 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.0-RC4].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I have also tried the following with no luck:

```
composer require craftcms/plugin-installer --ignore-platform-regs
```

Note my composer.json file shows the following:

```
{

"minimum-stability": "dev",
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
],
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform":{
        "php":"7.1.1"
    }
},
"require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "3.0.0-RC4"
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! On a side note this is a local install using Mamp Pro.

Comment: Is there a reason you're manually doing `composer require craftcms/plugin-installer`?  `craftcms/cms` requires it directly and https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/installation.md#2-create-a-new-craft-project pulls it in for you.

Comment: Something I unfortunately forgot to mention is that I'm upgrading from Craft 2 to Craft 3. I was following Mijingo's "Upgrade Craft 2 to 3" video and I can't get past the require craftcms/plugin-installer command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem following that video, i assume the ReleaseCandidate upgrade differs from the beta upgrade. Following the instructions from the craftcms github repo worked for me. https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html

Comment: Thanks Karl. That did the trick for me as well.

Comment: instruction doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Now that craft 3 is released you should use https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html to upgrade from v2 to v3.